# When I export a Grafana Dashboard, the file is huge

Tags: json, grafana

I click export to JSON for a Grafana dashboard, but I get a 43M file which includes all of the data.   I did try the sharing feature yesterday, but that appeared to hang - perhaps it was trying to share 43M of JSON.   Now I am unable to generate a usable export of my dashboard with just it's definition and none of the data.  What is the correct procedure to export the dashboard?

Comment: Indeed - When I took the snapshot, the snapshot data wound up in the .json file permanently.   That looks like a bug.

         "snapshotData": [
            {
              "datapoints": [
                [
                  -1,
                  1497308190000
                ],

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to export a snapshot dashboard. Having snapshot data in the json is not a bug as it is not the original dashboard. Snapshots are a way of sharing both a dashboard and some data and this feature allows you to share snapshots with someone who does not have access to your Time Series Database.

If you export the json from the original dashboard then it should only export the json.

If you are in the snapshot there should be a link to the original dashboard:

[image]

If you do not have the original dashboard anymore, then you can manually edit the json. Remove the `snapshotData` field and then re-import the file as a new dashboard.

Comment: I had attempted to create a snapshot at one point.  But it seems that now every single export contains snapshot data even if I have not subsequently requested it.

Comment: I added some details to the answer about how to either navigate to the original dashboard or how to recreate it if you no longer have it. How did you manage to get into this situation in the first place? It is quite hard to get the json for a snapshot via the Grafana UI.

Comment: I saved the .json to a file, and then used vi.

Comment: But how did you get the snapshot json from the UI? Or did you get it via Chrome Dev tools or the API? If it is possible via the UI, we need to fix that. (or fix it so that the data is stripped out).